# Is it legal for a vending machine (company) to offer additional purchase options after currency has been inserted?

Tags: commerce

Would it be legal to have a vending machine which could, let’s say through a touchscreen, offer different purchase options.

For example a $1 soda machine.  You put in the dollar and push the cola button.  The machine has the screen and, randomly, flashes two buttons… Continue with cola purchase or entertain different options.

You click different options and perhaps it asks:

“Would you like two root beers instead? One will not be cold because we’d ask if you to have it later, perhaps with a meal.”

Or maybe...
“ we like to have more people try our orange soda. For an additional $.50 you can have two cans of orange soda.”

Comment: Is the display presenting a reasonably navigable path to the original offer that was presented?

Comment: Oh absolutely...Gotta always be a button that says complete original purchase.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any law making this illegal.

You need to avoid any "bait and switch" tactics, though, like initially offering cola for $1 and then not actually letting them buy it for that price.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where this would run afoul of the law in the United States. People have been upselling for as long as they've been selling, and you seems pretty similar to what happens at most gas pumps nowadays: Would you like a car wash? How about some wiper fluid?